# Porque me elimina hasta la etiqueta creada Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente script sencillo que agrega etiquetas `<sup>` al numero 10 cuando haces click en el primer boton, y el segundo boton elimina el contenido del texto del div con clase container cuando es clickeado. Mi problema es que al tener varias etiquetas `<sup>` y luego haces click en el boton, te elimina esas etiquetas. ¿ Porque sucede esto ? , exactamente deberia eliminar solo el texto y no la etiqueta. Gracias de antemano.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
  const addButton = document.getElementById('add_power'),
        delButton = document.getElementById('delete_power'),
        div = document.querySelector('.container');

  const addText = a =>{

    div.textContent = a;

  }

  addButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    let power = document.createElement('sup');
    let power_text = document.createTextNode('x');

    power.appendChild(power_text);

    div.appendChild(power);

  });

  delButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{

    addText(div.textContent.slice(0, -1));

  })
})
```

```css
body{
font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<button id="add_power">Agregar potencia</button>
<button id="delete_power">Eliminar potencia</button>
<div contenteditable="true" class="container" style="margin-top: 10px; outline: 2px red solid; padding: 10px; display: table;">10</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el uso de la propiedad `textContent` ignora las etiquetas HTML, con lo que al editar el contenido las estás perdiendo.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('.container');

function showText(comment) {
  console.log(comment,div.textContent);
}

function addText(text) {
  div.textContent = text;
}

function addPower() {
  showText("Solo tenemos texto")
  const power = document.createElement('sup');
  const power_text = document.createTextNode('x');
  power.appendChild(power_text);
  div.appendChild(power);
  showText("Hemos añadido una etiqueta sup, pero se ignora al obtener el textContent:");

}

function deletePower () {
  showText("Lo que se obtiene, antes de quitar un carácter");
  addText(div.textContent.slice(0, -1));
  showText("Lo que queda");
}

setTimeout(() => {
  addPower();
},1000);

setTimeout(() => {
  deletePower();
},2000);
```

```css
body{
font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" class="container" style="margin-top: 10px; outline: 2px red solid; padding: 10px; display: table;">10</div>
```

Una opción sería editar el contenido buscando el hijo a borrar en el dom:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
  const addButton = document.getElementById('add_power'),
        delButton = document.getElementById('delete_power'),
        div = document.querySelector('.container');

  
  addButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    let power = document.createElement('sup');
    let power_text = document.createTextNode('x');

    power.appendChild(power_text);

    div.appendChild(power);

  });

  delButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    const lastPower = div.querySelector("sup:last-child");
    if (lastPower) {
      lastPower.remove();
    }
  })
})
```

```css
body{
font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<button id="add_power">Agregar potencia</button>
<button id="delete_power">Eliminar potencia</button>
<div contenteditable="true" class="container" style="margin-top: 10px; outline: 2px red solid; padding: 10px; display: table;">10</div>
```

Comment: gracias !!, tendre en cuenta tu respuesta cuando programe.